# BAD Request error while accessing rest service

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I am developing one mobile application using jQuery mobile controls.

I have rest services which I am using for getting data.

Currently I've two rest services, from those I am able to connect with one but while accessing other rest service I am getting error as 'Bad Request'. Please check web.config for both services.

When I hit service URL in browser then I am able to access service.

For example,

```
http://[ServerIP]:83/AccountAnalysisRestService/AccountAnalysisRestService.svc
```

This gives me response.

But I've one method as GetClients in rest service, when I try to access this method I am getting 'BAD Request' Error.

I am testing this on iPhone.

Also please help me how to post my web.config code here?